# Path in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get file from firestore with path: images/flowers. How can I get into 'flowers' subcollection? I need it as snapshots.

I tired this but didn't work:

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection('images')
            .document()
            .collection('others')
            .snapshots()
```

I want to get path to the subcollection 'others':

[image]

Comment: Firestore doesn't support storing files, it only supports json document. Are you referring to firestorage to retrieve a file from bucket? Please provide more insights.

Comment: Hello, you are right, I stored images in storage and saved links to them in firestore. I am getting pictures in app via links. And I need link from this path images/flowers

Comment: Firstore doesn't have "folders", so it's not clear what you're trying to do.  Paths to documents always follow alternating pairs of collections and documents.  I suggest explaining your end goal in more detail, perhaps using a screenshot or some other description of what you're seeing.

Comment: Without seeing your data, there's not much we can do.  You will need to be able to build the full path to a collection or document in order to query it, and we don't know what that path is.  Maybe you would like to show a screenshot or describe in more detail the nesting of collections and documents you're working with.

Comment: Thank you, I updated question with screenshots. I want to get into 'others' subcollection. "Firestore.instance
            .collection('images')
            .document()
            .collection('others')
            .snapshots()"  this is what I tried and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what document you want to get. If you want the 'others'-collection for all of them you first need to get the previous collection and iterate over them or better yet, set up a StreamBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a path to a subcollection, you need to know **all** of the path components.  Right now, you are ignoring the required document ID under which the subcollection is nested.  Passing no arguments to `document()` will just generate a random document ID, which obviously won't exist at the time of the query.  If you don't know the full path to a collection, then you won't be able to query it.